# chkrootkit throws Signal 13 when searching through /var/tmp

Tags: chkrootkit

On my debian squeeze server in the chkrootkit log I get loads of these errors:

```
/usr/bin/find: Prozeß "head" wurde durch das Signal 13 abgebrochen.
/usr/bin/find: Prozeß "head" wurde durch das Signal 13 abgebrochen.
```

which means

```
head terminated by signal 13
```

A [google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=head%20terminated%20by%20signal%2013) gives a lot of same problems, but no solution.

It comes from these lines in `/usr/sbin/chkrootkit`:

```
if [ `echo abc | head -n 1` = "abc" ]; then
      fileshead="`${find} ${ROOTDIR}tmp ${ROOTDIR}var/tmp ${findargs} -type f -exec head -n 1 {} \; | $egrep '#!.*php' 2> /dev/null`"
else
      fileshead="`${find} ${ROOTDIR}tmp ${ROOTDIR}var/tmp ${findargs} -type f -exec head -1 {} \; | grep '#!.*php' 2> /dev/null`"
fi
```

when I enter directly as root:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/tmp -type f -exec head -1 {} \; | grep php 2> /dev/null;date
```

I get the same errors. `egrep` instead makes no difference.

Comment: I solved that problem temporarily by commenting out these lines in the chkrootkit script, but that is not a solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chkrootkit searches for PHP files in /tmp/ and /var/tmp directories. Most likely, some files there trigger the bug.
In my case, it was a test file with lots of zero bytes - deleting the file solved the issue.

Comment: I created a testfile with lots of nullbytes with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/tmp/nullbytes count=1 bs=1M` but the command `/usr/bin/find /var/tmp -type f -exec head -1 {} \; | grep php 2> /dev/null;date
` did not throw any errors. could it be, that the error is fixed since wheezy?

Comment: I had a similar file of 1GB length. Ubuntu Precise; maybe newer versions do not have this bug.

Comment: That's it! I created an 1GB file with only zero bytes and then I got the error again. so deleting that temp file is the solution. A pity, that I don't know, how such a file could have been created there in the first place

Comment: I reported this to this debian bugreport: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588121

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation of the ideas behind Alex's answer below. I commented out the code at about line 1241 of the main chkrootkit shell script, and added replacement code following it:

```bsh
###if [ `echo abc | head -n 1` = "abc" ]; then
###      fileshead="`${find} ${ROOTDIR}tmp ${ROOTDIR}var/tmp ${findargs} -type f -exec head -n 1 {} \; | $egrep '#!.*php' 2> /dev/null`" 
###else
###      fileshead="`${find} ${ROOTDIR}tmp ${ROOTDIR}var/tmp ${findargs} -type f -exec head -1 {} \; | grep '#!.*php' 2> /dev/null`"
###fi

SUFF=`date "+%m%d%H%M%S.%N"`
echo > /tmp/matches.$SUFF

for F in `${find} ${ROOTDIR}tmp ${ROOTDIR}var/tmp ${findargs} -type f -print`
do
    read line <$F
    match=`echo "$line" | grep '#!.*php' 2> /dev/null`
    if [ -n "$match" ]
    then
        echo "$F : $match" >> /tmp/matches.$SUFF
    fi
done

fileshead=`cat /tmp/matches.$SUFF`
rm -f /tmp/matches.$SUFF
```

This works, and allows chkrootkit to complete.

Comment: Cool, did you send this patch to the Debian Bugtracker? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588121

Comment: I did just now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `head` at exit close the `stdout`, the first `head` output work correctly but any other write to the stdout fail with `SIGPIPE`.

You may want to use a different approach

`head -q -n1 $(find /somedir/ -type f)|grep someword`

**edit**

save a script like the one below somewhere, name it as you like, make it executable and replace `head` in the chkrootkit.

```
#!/bin/sh
shift
test -f "$1" || exit 1
read line <$1 
echo "$line"
```

It isn't full `head` compatible, so use it only on the part of chkrootkit that you've posted here.

Comment: so how would I repair the command in my question accordingly? It is the original chkrootkit-script