# Create a test file with lots of zero bytes

Tags: command-line, files

I know how to create an empty file:

```
touch /var/tmp/nullbytes
```

but how can I create a 1MB file that only contains nullbytes on the commandline with bash?

Comment: Relates SU question: http://superuser.com/q/609020/151431

Comment: +1. Interesting question. Could someone kindly elaborate in which scenarios would such a file be required..?

Comment: I needed it to simulate a crash on chkrootkit: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86866/chkrootkit-throws-signal-13-when-searching-through-var-tmp/102580?noredirect=1#comment156784_102580

Answer (score 67, accepted):

With GNU `truncate`:

```
truncate -s 1M nullbytes
```

(assuming `nullbytes` didn't exist beforehand) would create a 1 mebibyte sparse file. That is a file that appears filled with zeros but that doesn't take any space on disk.

Without `truncate`, you can use `dd` instead:

```
dd bs=1048576 seek=1 of=nullbytes count=0
```

(with some `dd` implementations, you can replace 1048576 with `1M`)

If you'd rather the disk space be *allocated*, on Linux and some filesystems, you could do:

```
fallocate -l 1M nullbytes
```

That allocates the space without actually writing data to the disk (the space is reserved but marked as uninitialised).

```
dd < /dev/zero bs=1048576 count=1 > nullbytes
```

Will actually write the zeros to disk. That is the least efficient, but if you need your drives to spin when accessing that file, that's the one you'll want to go for.

Or @mikeserv's way to trick `dd` into generating the NUL bytes:

```
dd bs=1048576 count=1 conv=sync,noerror 0> /dev/null > nullbytes
```

An alternative with GNU `head` that doesn't involve having to specify a block size (1M is OK, but 10G for instance wouldn't):

```
head -c 1M < /dev/zero > nullbytes
```

Or to get a progress bar:

```
pv -Ss 1M < /dev/zero > nullbytes
```

Comment: Don't use `truncate` for creating an empty file to be used as swap volume… this will not work! Use `dd` in this case instead.

Comment: @EliasProbst, ITYM _copy from /dev/zero instead_, _do not use a sparse file_. `dd` can create sparse files as I showed as well.

Comment: fallocate is the best and fast way to create because it reserves the space and do it fast but it doesn't bother to write anything (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system)

Comment: ...or `bs=1kx1k`. Or `<&1 dd bs=1kx1k conv=sync,noerror count="$rpt" | cat >file` for the literal write to disk thing. Not 100% on how much efficiency might be lost in forcing the read error, though.

Answer (score 32):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/tmp/nullbytes count=1 bs=1M
```